# Images in div width 100%, aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, height, width

Goodday,

I want to know how you can made something like the following website?
http://modeltheme.com/travelogue/background-image/

If you resize the window the images fill the page for 100%. But if an image width doesn't fit the width it gets below and the other image fill the page back.

How can I made this for my own? Know somebody how?

Comment: You might want to watch basic CSS tutorials. Otherwise, show us a bit of your code and we can help you.

Comment: I just see  basic grid ... can you clarify what behavior?

Comment: you could view the page source and see the code how they did it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work for each resolution. This will spread the image on whole container.

```
<style>
 .background_cover{ background-size:cover;}
</style>
```